# Map A Recursive Tree to A Flat List with conditions

Tags: c#

I'm writing a c# app and I have a recursive tree that looks like this:

```
Item1
|-Container(min 0, max 1)
| |-Item2
| | |-Container(min 0, max 1)
| |   |-Item5
| |-Item3
| | |-Container(min 1, max 1)
| |   |-Item8
|-Container(min 1, max 1)
| |-Item4
| |-Item7
|-Container(min 1, max 1)
  |-Item6
```

And I need to convert it to a list as follows:

```
Item1-Item6-Item4
Item1-Item6-Item4-Item2
Item1-Item6-Item4-Item2-Item5
Item1-Item6-Item4-Item3-Item8
Item1-Item6-Item7
Item1-Item6-Item7-Item2
Item1-Item6-Item7-Item2-Item5
Item1-Item6-Item7-Item3-Item8
```

following those condition:

- if a container has min greater than 0 then its items should always added to parent item like `item4`, `item7` and `item6`,
- if not it should be added to the essential items like `item2`, `item3`, and `item5`,
- items of the same container is not grouped in the same set

Comment: What have you tried so far ?

Comment: Nothing solid ... I got very confused in the middle of it ... as it has other dependencies

Comment: I believe a recursive method should fix this but I'm stuck figuring it out

Comment: How about the container which contains Item4 has another item?

Comment: yeah it can have other items

Comment: Looks like you algorithm is trying to balance a binary tree similar to following wiki article : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-balancing_binary_search_tree

Comment: it looks like it but I'm forming a flat list instead ...

Comment: I reviewed the required result and edited it ... if you can please recheck it

Comment: Your requirement is dim, item6 is always appended, but item4 and item7 is appended sometimes. As your description they **should always added**. Then if the last container contains 1 more item, how the result will be? Another question is about the order, Are both Item1-Item6-Item4 and Item1-Item4-Item6 ok?

Comment: Maybe I think too much, is it possible the item5 container has a min value 1?

Comment: Items in same container cannot be appended to the same grouping ... order is not required, so yeah both are ok ... if item5 container has min value 1 it will change the resulted set

Comment: if item5 container has min value 1 this set will be removed `Item1-Item6-Item7-Item2`

Comment: I mean item5's container has min = 1, and item2's container keep min = 0, the child container's min value is greater than parent. If it is possible, which one is right? `Item1-Item6-Item7-Item2-Item5` or `Item1-Item6-Item7-Item5` or both?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of thinking and tinkering I got to this solution:

My resulted structure will be a list of lists of items, this method will take the root item and the list of items so I can query the items with the bounded ids in containers

```
public static List<List<Item>> Map(Item item, List<Item> items)
{
    var result = new List<List<Item>> { new List<Item> { item } };
    item.Containers.ForEach(container =>
    {
        if (container.Min < 1)
        {
            var visited = new List<int>();
            container.ItemIds.ForEach(id =>
            {
                var localItem = items.Find(i => i.Id == id);
                var localItemList = Map(localItem, items);
                localItemList.Add(new List<Item>());
                var excludedVisited = result.Where(l => !l.Any(i => visited.Contains(i.Id))).ToList();
                var remainingNodes = result.Where(l => l.Any(i => visited.Contains(i.Id))).ToList();
                result = Product(excludedVisited, localItemList).Union(remainingNodes).ToList();
                visited.Add(id);
            });
        }
        else
        {
            var visited = new List<int>();
            var localResult = new List<List<Item>>();
            container.ItemIds.ForEach(id =>
            {
                var localItem = items.Find(i => i.Id == id);
                var localItemList = Map(localItem, items);
                var excludedVisited = result.Where(l => !l.Any(i => visited.Contains(i.Id))).ToList();
                var remainingNodes = result.Where(l => l.Any(i => visited.Contains(i.Id))).ToList();
                localResult.AddRange(Product(excludedVisited, localItemList).Union(remainingNodes).ToList());
                visited.Add(id);
            });
            result = localResult;
        }
    });
    return result;
}
```

you can find a sample of its usage [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/JGF8b8)